# PHP (array_keys) function not return all indexes except some keys in for loop

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I'm trying to get indexes(keys) from the unsorted array but something I'm doing wrong.
This is my two arrays:

```
$unsorted = [1,2,1,14,3,1,3,6,1,13,83,4, 4 ,68];
$sorted = [83,68,14,13,6,4,4,3,3,2,1,1,1,1];
```

I tried the `array_keys()`.The below code is working

```
$a = array_keys($unsorted,$sorted[0]);
print_r($a);
echo '<br>';
```

The output

> Array ( [0] => 10 )

but inside for loop it is not. please suggest me where I'm doing wrong

```
for($y=0;$y<sizeOf($sorted);$y++) {
    $final_keys = array_keys($unsorted,$sorted[$y]);
    //$final[] = $final_two[$y];
}
print_r($final_keys);
```

The output is

> Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 2 [2] => 5 [3] => 8 )

what I expect is

> Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 [2] => 3 [3] => 9 [4] => 7 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 4 [8] => 6 [9] => 1 [10] => 0 [11] => 2 [12] => 5 [13] => 8 )

Comment: wait what, why not just `array_keys($unsorted)`?

Comment: the first output `0 => 10` gives you the right key/index (10) for the searched item ('83') of in the first array.

Comment: Yes @Jeff but please look at the second output

Comment: Your script is working, just put `print_r` inside the loop. -> https://3v4l.org/h0VLR

Comment: @Dimitrov The problem is storing those indexes into an array.

Comment: @Aroon how would you like them sorted? by value, by key value?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs by values using rsort()

Comment: @Aroon you're `what I expect is` result isn't sorted rsort though ? o.O

Comment: But why do you need positions of elements? Maybe you're trying to solve some other problem?

Comment: also what is the purpose of the script? why are you for looping if you just want the keys of the $unsorted array?

Comment: _“please suggest me where I'm doing wrong”_ - you are overwriting `$final_keys` in each loop iteration, so after the loop it contains only the positions where the last entry of your sorted array, which is 1, was found.

Comment: I'm doing some other operations by having this indexes because all of the arrays are same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop `$sorted`, find the key/value pair in `$unsorted` and store. And set the value in `$unsorted` (I made a copy, not to destroy the original) to false, otherwise `1` would always find the first value of `1`.

```
$unsorted = [1,2,1,14,3,1,3,6,1,13,83,4, 4 ,68];
$sorted = [83,68,14,13,6,4,4,3,3,2,1,1,1,1];
$copy = $unsorted;
$output=[];

foreach ($sorted as $key => $value){
  $reference = array_search( $value , $copy );
  $output[$key] = $reference;
  $copy[$reference] = false;
  }
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 11
    [6] => 12
    [7] => 4
    [8] => 6
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 2
    [12] => 5
    [13] => 8
)
```

Comment: In this output the second index is not 9 its 13. please have a look

Comment: @Aroon. The second value in `$unsorted` is `2`. The key of value `2` in `$sorted` is `9`. Hence `[1] => 9`.

Comment: There  I'm looking for 13 cuz 68th index value is 13 in $unsorted

Comment: @mickmackusa. I don't see why not. `array_search()` just looks for the value, returning the key.

Comment: @Aroon, you want it the other way round? Not `$unsorted => $sorted` but `$sorted => $unsorted`?

Comment: sorry to confusing you. I want to get the values from sorted array and based on the values i want keys from unsorted array. like 83's key should be 10 and 68 th should be 13  like so on

Answer (score 2):

You can simply sort your array while maintaining the index association, and then gets the keys of the resulting array:

```
$unsorted = [1,2,1,14,3,1,3,6,1,13,83,4, 4 ,68];
$temp = $unsorted; // create a copy, in case you need still need the unsorted version later on
arsort($temp); // sort values in reverse order, while keeping the keys
$keys = array_keys($temp);
var_dump($keys);
```

Comment: @Aroon Is there anything that isn't absolutely perfect about this answer?

Comment: @mickmackusa I’m getting a slightly different result here with my code, than in the question/accepted answer, `[0]=>10 [1]=>13 [2]=>3 [3]=>9 [4]=>7 [5]=>11 [6]=>12 [7]=>6 [8]=>4 [9]=>1 [10]=>2 [11]=>5 [12]=>0 [13]=>8` I guess the duplicate values in the original data make it slightly ambiguous, what should be considered the “correct” result here.

Comment: Something is strange to me.  I'm pretty sure if this was my project, I'd be doing what you're doing.  Perhaps I'll re-read this page a few times. Perhaps php's Quick Sort is to blame.

Comment: @mickmackusa I guess the difference comes from that my solution maintains the index association throughout, whereas with the original question and the already given “sorted” data, there is no way to tell _which_ of the `1,1,1,1` at the end was which to begin with. And then when `array_search` gets used (on $copy, in the accepted answer), it will always find the _first_ 1 every time, because it can’t differentiate between the multiple occurrences either ...

Comment: Ah ha! Nope, not your fault.  It's a php version issue.  PHP5.6 doesn't sort the duplicates like php7+.  Look at this: https://3v4l.org/TYkkb  upvoting this answer because it will be faaaaaaar more efficient than iterated `array_search()` calls.

Comment: @Aroon what php version are you using?

Comment: Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other.sort-order

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving the output:
$final_keys is a regular variable being repopulated. or an array being repopulated in its case

```
$final_keys = array() ;
for($y=0;$y<sizeOf($sorted);$y++) {
$final_keys[] = array_keys($unsorted,$sorted[$y]);
//$final[] = $final_two[$y];
 }
print_r($final_keys);
```

you can also add each array to `$final_keys` the proper key:

```
$final_keys = array() ;
for($y=0;$y<sizeOf($sorted);$y++) {
$final_keys[$y] = array_keys($unsorted,$sorted[$y]);
//$final[] = $final_two[$y];
 }
print_r($final_keys);
```

Comment: I tried this method before I post but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution using array_search()

```
$unsorted = [1,2,1,14,3,1,3,6,1,13,83,4, 4 ,68];
$sorted = [83,68,14,13,6,4,4,3,3,2,1,1,1,1];

foreach($sorted as $value) {
    $final_keys[] = $tempKey = array_search($value,$unsorted);
    unset($unsorted[$tempKey]);
}
print_r($final_keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because array_search is a slow operation, using results in quadratic complexity. Instead, you can use linear complexity by making two passes through the array.

```
$unsorted = [1,2,1,14,3,1,3,6,1,13,83,4, 4 ,68];
$sorted = [83,68,14,13,6,4,4,3,3,2,1,1,1,1];

$temp = [];
foreach($unsorted as $k=>$v) {
    $temp[$v][] = $k;
}

$res = [];
foreach($sorted as $v) {
    $res[] = array_shift($temp[$v]);
}

print_r($res);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/af6b6801896ee437943306ed9575932449186f91)